# Why do I get a ECONNREFUSED error after trying to reconnect my TCP connection in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to open a TCP connection in Node.js to another program using the following command:

```
connection = net.connect(18003, function() {
});

connection.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
connection.on('error', function() {
  console.log('Connection error');

  setTimeout(function () {
    connection = net.connect(18003, ipAddress,
      function() {
    });
  }, 10000); //Try to reconnect
});
```

If the other program's not running (therefor not listening) the connection error is handled correctly the first time, but if I try to connect again (unsuccessfully) after a timeout I get the following error:

```
events.js:68
  throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Does anyone now why the unsuccessful connect is handled correctly the first time but not the second?  I'd like to keep trying the connection while waiting on the other program to start.

Comment: You need to re-register your `'error'` event handler for the newly created `connection`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to bind to the [`'error'` event](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error_1) with each retry as each call to [`net.connect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_port_host_connectlistener) returns a new [`net.Socket`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) with its own event bindings:

```
// ...
  setTimeout(function () {
    connection = net.connect(18003, ipAddress,
      function() {
    });

    connection.on('error', function () {
      console.log('Connection retry error');
    });
  }, 10000); //Try to reconnect
// ...
```

For continuously retrying, wrap the "setup" in a function that can be called as needed:

```
function setupConnection() {
  connection = net.connect(18003, ipAddress, function () {
  });

  connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
  });

  connection.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Connection error');

    setTimeout(setupConnection, 10000); //Try to reconnect
  });
}

setupConnection();
```

Comment: I would like to DoublePlusGood this answer as it saved me a lot of time.  Wrap the setup function, it will save a LOT of time.  Before calling the wrapped function on timeout, be sure to ```.close()``` or ```.destroy()``` the connection to prevent memory leaks.  And wait a few seconds to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Lonowski, while I was using ur code I noticed that on server restart it would open multiple connections. the 'error' event occurs before the closing of socket. moving the 
recursive call to socket close event works correctly.

```
function setupConnection() {
  connection = net.connect(18003, ipAddress, function () {
  });
  connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    setTimeout(setupConnection, 10000); //Try to reconnect EDITED
  });

  connection.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Connection error');
  });
}
setupConnection();
```